# Curl build with bash script

Tags: bash, curl, sh

I want to create `curl` with `#!/bin/sh` script and the part that giving me a headache is:

```
STR="-XGET -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer "$TOKEN"' https://my_endpoint/sth?"
echo $STR

CON="$(curl $STR)"
```

The echo there is:

> ```
> -XGET -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTM5NzIxODcsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoid2luZ3UtY2xpZW50LWFkbWluQHNwZWljaGVyMjEwLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6IjE0NTM4ODU3ODcifQ.ADLcrV4yph6owwgMLak2RsnC95WK17ULflCisvNWBkeA93G4WUQ-BMrjnhQeuIgSfxSYnAmgmI36ggc2PytWhkqk8lIYrMJTH80tggBYCnnuA2lM26IZ2ViUMK1cj-BH3-dh4HmqSm_hozAFnVqGQi9P5J4CBz8eCf_mKc3iq-7EnXRikTkgakF69-jPfFA_9yO26JzZeDpymowa-LRPafWPtYinzmkaUQ2SHjUdWtGmELAyzkGUOOXrZ8TgvV9Yeb-OnEoY54GRSlb4ogVzAwWCJ2Y6vxmvNpAN5wiUZMylqTGhnqFr9MOp4JId1RavjwT7STRp9bCHBxD55CtYoEQ-oSpDv6WkgB07CtCRi0Spx9ErVsaB0Xf1mH9XKAVjOQ_dNNpKTxlqIXMbbosxEhjYE9K6Z30c3uWhCgccNdEEHxPhi7d2bRO3M_3fJPKsYWWk5DXhxmkFpJ4fLf05JO31FFIoj8q7H3c5NEvXVk_keS-jPY5iP5xRY1dv9P8bWPEwFk1-qQrXZ1mMNiLDLxdB9cXE9Tm6Eo4Rxo71H2o4Z1DHmnVHHctsATzywsJIe3o8Ym5o0OsmS3WH3EJ-IS572lFv-ZQSkt3fq927JlvWotd9HHMT2MOPf8Zg5cdNd-hclZUfj7qOi-a0Afbn2cT3FccBXJ8l4' https://my_endpoint/sth?
> ```

And when i copy this from terminal and paste it into `curl` it works, but in the verbose log I find:

> ```
> -XGET -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTM5NzIxODcsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoid2luZ3UtY2xpZW50LWFkbWluQHNwZWljaGVyMjEwLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6IjE0NTM4ODU3ODcifQ.ADLcrV4yph6owwgMLak2RsnC95WK17ULflCisvNWBkeA93G4WUQ-BMrjnhQeuIgSfxSYnAmgmI36ggc2PytWhkqk8lIYrMJTH80tggBYCnnuA2lM26IZ2ViUMK1cj-BH3-dh4HmqSm_hozAFnVqGQi9P5J4CBz8eCf_mKc3iq-7EnXRikTkgakF69-jPfFA_9yO26JzZeDpymowa-LRPafWPtYinzmkaUQ2SHjUdWtGmELAyzkGUOOXrZ8TgvV9Yeb-OnEoY54GRSlb4ogVzAwWCJ2Y6vxmvNpAN5wiUZMylqTGhnqFr9MOp4JId1RavjwT7STRp9bCHBxD55CtYoEQ-oSpDv6WkgB07CtCRi0Spx9ErVsaB0Xf1mH9XKAVjOQ_dNNpKTxlqIXMbbosxEhjYE9K6Z30c3uWhCgccNdEEHxPhi7d2bRO3M_3fJPKsYWWk5DXhxmkFpJ4fLf05JO31FFIoj8q7H3c5NEvXVk_keS-jPY5iP5xRY1yirgabLv9P8bWPEwFk1-qQrXZ1mMNiLDLxdB9cXE9Tm6Eo4Rxo71H2o4Z1DHmnVHHctsATzywsJIe3o8Ym5o0OsmS3WH3EJ-IS572lFv-ZQSkt3fq927JlvWot5MN9HHMT2MOPf8Zg5c6udNd-hclZUfj7qOi-a0Afbn2cT3FccBXJ8l4' https://my_endpoint/sth?
> * Rebuilt URL to: Bearer/
>   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: Bearer
> * Closing connection 0
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
> * Rebuilt URL to: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTM5NzIxODcsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoid2luZ3UtY2xpZW50LWFkbWluQHNwZWljaGVyMjEwLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6IjE0NTM4ODU3ODcifQ.ADLcrV4yph6owwgMLak2RsnC95WK17ULflCisvNWBkeA93G4WUQ-BMrjnhQeuIgSfxSYnAmgmI36ggc2PytWhkqk8lIYrMJTH80tggBYCnnuA2lM26IZ2ViUMK1cj-BH3-dh4HmqSm_hozAFnVqGQi9P5J4CBz8eCf_mKc3iq-7EnXRikTkgakF69-jPfFA_9yO26JzZeDpymowa-LRPafWPtYinzmkaUQ2SHjUdWtGmELAyzkGUOOXrZ8TgvV9Yeb-OnEoY54GRSlb4ogVzAwWCJ2Y6vxmvNpAN5wiUZMylqTGhnqFr9MOp4JId1RavjwT7STRp9bCHBxD55CtYoEQ-oSpDv6WkgB07CtCRi0Spx9ErVsaB0Xf1mH9XKAVjOQ_dNNpKTxlqIXMbbosxEhjYE9K6Z30c3uWhCgccNdEEHxPhi7d2bRO3M_3fJPKsYWWk5DXhxmkFpJ4fLf05JO31FFIoj8q7H3c5NEvXVk_keS-jPY5iP5xRY1yirgabLv9P8bWPEwFk1-qQrXZ1mMNiLDLxdB9cXE9Tm6Eo4Rxo71H2o4Z1DHmnVHHctsATzywsJIe3o8Ym5o0OsmS3WH3EJ-IS572lFv-ZQSkt3fq927JlvWot5MN9HHMT2MOPf8Zg5c6udNd-hclZUfj7qOi-a0Afbn2cT3FccBXJ8l4'/
> * Could not resolve host: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTM5NzIxODcsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoid2luZ3UtY2xpZW50LWFkbWluQHNwZWljaGVyMjEwLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6IjE0NTM4ODU3ODcifQ.ADLcrV4yph6owwgMLak2RsnC95WK17ULflCisvNWBkeA93G4WUQ-BMrjnhQeuIgSfxSYnAmgmI36ggc2PytWhkqk8lIYrMJTH80tggBYCnnuA2lM26IZ2ViUMK1cj-BH3-dh4HmqSm_hozAFnVqGQi9P5J4CBz8eCf_mKc3iq-7EnXRikTkgakF69-jPfFA_9yO26JzZeDpymowa-LRPafWPtYinzmkaUQ2SHjUdWtGmELAyzkGUOOXrZ8TgvV9Yeb-OnEoY54GRSlb4ogVzAwWCJ2Y6vxmvNpAN5wiUZMylqTGhnqFr9MOp4JId1RavjwT7STRp9bCHBxD55CtYoEQ-oSpDv6WkgB07CtCRi0Spx9ErVsaB0Xf1mH9XKAVjOQ_dNNpKTxlqIXMbbosxEhjYE9K6Z30c3uWhCgccNdEEHxPhi7d2bRO3M_3fJPKsYWWk5DXhxmkFpJ4fLf05JO31FFIoj8q7H3c5NEvXVk_keS-jPY5iP5xRY1yirgabLv9P8bWPEwFk1-qQrXZ1mMNiLDLxdB9cXE9Tm6Eo4Rxo71H2o4Z1DHmnVHHctsATzywsJIe3o8Ym5o0OsmS3WH3EJ-IS572lFv-ZQSkt3fq927JlvWot5MN9HHMT2MOPf8Zg5c6udNd-hclZUfj7qOi-a0Afbn2cT3FccBXJ8l4'
> * Closing connection 1
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTM5NzIxODcsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoid2luZ3UtY2xpZW50LWFkbWluQHNwZWljaGVyMjEwLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6IjE0NTM4ODU3ODcifQ.ADLcrV4yph6owwgMLak2RsnC95WK17ULflCisvNWBkeA93G4WUQ-BMrjnhQeuIgSfxSYnAmgmI36ggc
> *   Trying 54.228.198.226...
> * Connected to my_endpoint (54.228.198.226) port 443 (#2)
> * TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> * Server certificate: *.herokuapp.com
> * Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
> * Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> > GET /api/sth? HTTP/1.1
> > Host: my_endpoint/sth?
> > User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> > Accept: */*
> >
> < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> < Connection: keep-alive
> < Server: nginx/1.8.0
> < Content-Type: application/json
> < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> < X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.17
> < Cache-Control: no-cache
> < Allow: GET
> < Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2016 09:09:49 GMT
> < Via: 1.1 vegur
> <
> { [59 bytes data]
> 100    48    0    48    0     0     41      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
> * Connection #2 to host my_endpoint left intact
> ```

What's wrong with that header?

Comment: You are using bash, but executing the command at windows. That's why!

Comment: No @SabujHassan, I'm executing it on mac.

Comment: For windows it happens when you are using single quote. For example single quote after `-H` header. Try with double quote.

Comment: I'm not using windows, when I fire `-XGET -v -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5c(...)CI6IkpXUyJ9.bjt3M"  https://my_endpoint/sth?` i got exactly the same result

Comment: Your modified command is perfect and it works nicely with me.

Comment: That what I post in question @SabujHassan when I paste it to terminal it works when I fire it from script it not working

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
eval curl $STR "https://my_endpoint" > 'output_file'
```

Comment: `eval` is unnecessary here at best, and is often a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array to store command arguments.

```
curl_options=(-XGET -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://my_endpoint/sth?")
content=$(curl "${curl_options[@]}")
```